# Highlighting all Cells with Error Value

Tags: vba, excel

I want to highlight cells in a worksheet having error values like #Name, #N/A , #Div/0!,  #REF! etc.

However, I can detect if these is any error in a sheet with the help of the following code, but cannot figure out how to highlight them, any suggestions?

```
If VarType(ActiveCell.Value) <> vbError Then
    ' Highlight ActiveSheet.cells.Interior.colorIndex = 3
 End If
```

Comment: You can do this without VBA by using Excel's built-in `Conditional Formatting` feature by using a custom formula of `=ISERROR(A1)` applied to each respective cell.

Comment: `Activecell.Interior.colorIndex = 3` would highlight the cell you are testing.

Comment: @Rory Tried your solution but its not working, highlights random cell..

Comment: Nope, it highlights the cell your code is testing - though you are testing for cells that are **not** errors in that code.

Comment: @Rory I checked again , but its not working. I'm using Excel 2016. Can't say why its picking the random cell. However  Scott Holtzman worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution to my problem without using conditional formatting.

```
sub highlightErrorCells
  Worksheets(wsName).Activate
  For Each R In Worksheets(wsName).UsedRange
    If IsError(R.Value) Then
     Range(R.Address).Interior.colorIndex = 3
    End If
Next
```

end sub

Comment: Have a look at a similar solution, but much faster than looping through a range at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46806394/for-loop-setting-font-and-interior-of-range-taking-way-too-long/46806750#46806750